# The << operator in Cpp error

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, cout

How does the compiler distinguishes between the following cases :

```
cout << a; //Case 1 :prints a

cout << a << b; // Case 2 :prints both a and b

cout << (a << b); // Case 3 :Left shifts a by b bits and prints shifted a

cout << a&b;   // Case 4 :Throws an ERROR
```

In most of the cases the compiler self assumes as it seems that << with cout without proper bracketing is always for *insertion* to output stream. But why does it fails in the last case, IMO : this should have properly given the answer of a bitwise b. If I do bracketing, it does gives correct as :

```
cout<< (a&b);  //gives correct output of bitwise and a , b.
```

Why does the error occurs in the 4th case ?

Comment: Just have a look at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for C++ Operator Precedence :)

Comment: That would be due to operator precedence. Also, there is the notion of binary operators like `<<` which accept a left and a right side argument. For `cout`, they'll return `cout` so that it can continue on its way. When you get operator precedence wrong though...

Comment: I know very well << has a greater precedence than & but why isnt it evident that << is _insertion_ operator and not left shift in 4th case ? @George

Comment: @Akash: Precedence doesn't care how the operators are overloaded. `cout` could define `<<` as the order-a-pizza operator and the precedence wouldn't change.

Comment: @user2357112 : comprehending what AndyG also said : It implies that << as _insertion_ and left shift have the same precedence, it just the matter of associativity as evident from case 2 ... am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluation of a chain of `<<` operators goes left-to-right. Therefore,

```
cout << a << b;
```

is the same as

```
(cout << a) << b;
```

Since `cout << a` expression returns `cout`, you end up with both `a` and `b` in the output stream.

When you change the order with parentheses, the meaning of `<<` changes to left shifting.

When you replace the second `<<` with `&`, the situation changes, because now [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) begins to matter. `&` has lower precedence than `<<`, so

```
cout << a & b;
```

is interpreted as

```
(cout << a) & b;
```

This expression requires an operator `&` that takes an input stream on the left and an integer on the right. Since such operator does not exist, the compiler reports an error.

When you force the order of evaluation again using parentheses, the compiler sees that you apply `<<` to an output stream and an integer, so it computes `(a&b)`, and writes it out to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that << for cout  binds first in the case shown(same as left shift) and how it behaves was not clear. Idk why people downvoted the question just thinking about operator precedence